# ckeditor validation using jquery in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor  in my website.I want to validate ckeditor using jquery.I tried several scripts but I am unable to do it.following is code

```
var ckeditorinstance = jQuery("#<%=ck.ClientID%>").ckeditorGet();
                    var eventsummary = CKEDITOR.instances[ckeditorinstance].getData();
```

OR

```
eventsummary = jQuery("#<%=ck.ClientID%>").html();
```

OR

```
eventsummary = jQuery("#<%=ck.ClientID%>").VAL();

<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="abc1" BasePath="/CC/" TabIndex="13" runat="server"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl
```

No one is working

Answer (score 0):

Try this -
HTML

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="descriptionTextBox" runat="server" Rows="12" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="desc"></asp:TextBox>
    <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
        CKEDITOR.replace('<%=descriptionTextBox.ClientID%>');
        CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true
    </script>
```

jQuery Validate

```
    var textBoxId = $(".desc").attr('id');
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[textBoxId];
    editor.updateElement();
    if ($('#' + '<%= descriptionTextBox.ClientID %>').val().trim() == '') {
        alert('value is required')                
    }
```

Regards.